# How to ignore WHERE IN clause if subquery did not find junctions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting transactions from a table using the following query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE t.id IN
(
  SELECT t2.id
  FROM `virtual_account-account` AS vaa
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2
  ON t2.account = vaa.account
  WHERE vaa.virtual_account = 3
)
AND t.id IN
(
  SELECT tt.transaction
  FROM `virtual_account-tag` AS vat
  LEFT JOIN `transaction-tag` AS tt
  ON tt.tag = vat.tag
  WHERE vat.virtual_account = 3
)
ORDER BY t.date
```

However, I'd like to modify this such that if, e.g., the junction table `virtual_account-account` does not contain any junctions where `vaa.virtual_account = 3`, then the corresponding `t.id IN (...)` condition should be ignored. Thus far, I've failed to find a solution for this so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about if both Sub-Selects return nothing? Do you want to show all transactions or just none?

Comment: @FabianBigler Actually, I don't care too much about that situation as this will not be possible to occur. However, an empty result would be better than selecting all transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Just an **OR** between both conditions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE t.id IN
(
  SELECT t2.id
  FROM `virtual_account-account` AS vaa
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2
  ON t2.account = vaa.account
  WHERE vaa.virtual_account = 3
)
OR t.id IN
(
  SELECT tt.transaction
  FROM `virtual_account-tag` AS vat
  LEFT JOIN `transaction-tag` AS tt
  ON tt.tag = vat.tag
  WHERE vat.virtual_account = 3
)
ORDER BY t.date
```

If one is returning nothing, it will still return the other transactions.

Comment: he sait it should be ignored

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it's not that simple: IF there are entries in both junction tables (`virtual_account-account` resp. `virtual_account-tag`) with ID 3, then there should be an AND condition.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach turns the subquery into a join and uses a variable to count the number of rows in the subquery.  The `where` clause then uses this variable for the logic you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t left outer join
     (SELECT t2.id, @cnt := @cnt + 1
      FROM `virtual_account-account` AS vaa
           LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2
           ON t2.account = vaa.account cross join
           (select @cnt := 0)
      WHERE vaa.virtual_account = 3
      group by t2.id
     ) c1
     on c1.id = t.id
WHERE (c1.id is not null or @cnt = 0) and
      t.id IN (SELECT tt.transaction
               FROM `virtual_account-tag` AS vat
                    LEFT JOIN `transaction-tag` AS tt
                    ON tt.tag = vat.tag
              WHERE vat.virtual_account = 3
      )
ORDER BY t.date;
```

Note that the subquery eliminates duplicates (uses `group by`).  Otherwise, you might have the problem of multiple matches resulting in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

A bit clumsy and verbose, but...

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE t.id IN
(
  SELECT t2.id
  FROM `virtual_account-account` AS vaa
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2
  ON t2.account = vaa.account
  WHERE vaa.virtual_account = 3
)
AND t.id IN
(
  SELECT tt.transaction
  FROM `virtual_account-tag` AS vat
  LEFT JOIN `transaction-tag` AS tt
  ON tt.tag = vat.tag
  WHERE vat.virtual_account = 3
  AND EXISTS
    (
      SELECT t2.id
      FROM `virtual_account-account` AS vaa
      LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2
      ON t2.account = vaa.account
      WHERE vaa.virtual_account = 3
    )
)
ORDER BY t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (select count(*) vaa 
      FROM `virtual_account-account`
      WHERE virtual_account = 3) a
CROSS JOIN (select count(*) vat
            FROM `virtual_account-tag`
            WHERE virtual_account = 3) g
CROSS JOIN transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN `virtual_account-account` vaa
       ON t.id = vaa.id AND vaa.virtual_account = 3
LEFT JOIN `virtual_account-tag` vat
     JOIN `transaction-tag` tt ON tt.tag = vat.tag
       ON t.id = tt.transaction AND vat.virtual_account = 3
WHERE (a.vaa = 0 OR vaa.id IS NOT NULL) AND
      (g.vat = 0 OR vat.tag IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.date
```